# How do programs choose which icon to use

Tags: icons

(I edited this question as I wasn't clear about application icon and status icon).

I have made a few of my own icons, nothing fancy, just changed a dozen or so icons to fit in better with my setup. In my `theme.index` file I set the inherits to the main theme.

So far so good, except for one particular program, `simplescreenrecorder`. This program will not pick up the status icons in my theme folder, it always and only picks up an icon from the `hicolor` folder. It does however pick up the application icon from my theme folder.

Not a problem, I just tweaked the icon in the `hicolor` folder.

So my question is why? I thought if I found the icon a program was using and made another icon in my own icon folder with the same name it would override the `hicolor` icon. It does for all the other programs (so far at least).

I suppose question 2 should then be is there any way I can find out which icon a program (or daemon or notification...whatever) uses for status.

I have noticed other themes have status icons for simplescreenrecorder and they do not get picked either.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is: how did you  (try to) make the applications pick a custom icon?

Comment: I haven't tried to make applications pick a custom icon.  For example, if I load the elementary-xfce icon theme, or any other icon theme for that matter, programs like Firefox, Thunderbird, Gimp, Putty, etc all use the icon from the chosen theme, without any intervention from me. If I make my own them, inherit elementary-xfe (which eventually inherits hicolor), Firefox, Thunderbird, Gimp etc all use the icon from my them (if I have made one and named it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

If you look in /usr/share/applications/, you'll find a lot of files that end in .desktop. These .desktop files associate icons with applications.

In `terminal`, if you `cat /usr/share/applications/shotwell.desktop` you'll find a line that says `Icon=`. You can change this to the full pathname of another icon of your choice. However, software updates may replace this file and remove any edits that you make.

A better way is to copy a given .desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit the `Icon=` line there.

The Icon= is only for the main application icon. For internal icons, you'll have to look for a simplescreenrecorder folder in `/usr/share/icons` or `/usr/share/pixmaps`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I'm looking for. Going to have a play with that tonight and if it works (and I'm sure it will) I'll mark the answer as correct. Cheers :)

Comment: Just had a very quick look (I am in work !) and for simplescreenrecorder it lists "Icon=simplescreenrecorder".  That's fine, and in fact the main application icon is picked up from my theme folder (sorry, I mislead you there!) but the status icons "simplescreenrecorder-paused" and "simplescreenrecorder-recording" are not picked up.

Comment: The `Icon=` is only for the main application icon. For internal icons, you'll have to look for a `simplescreenrecorder` folder in `/usr/share/icons` or `/usr/share/pixmaps`.

Comment: There are 'simplescreenrecorder' icons in /usr/share/icons/<theme>, but like I say the application only ever uses the status icons from the 'hicolor' theme, but does use the application icon from the current theme.  I guess the application is hard coded to only use the hicolor icon ? I ended up editing the 'hicolor' icons to something to suit me, but would prefer to figure out how to make 'simplescreenrecorder' use the status icons from the current icon theme.

Comment: Send the program author an email requesting help at maarten-baert@hotmail.com

Comment: Good idea, will do.

Comment: I emailed the author and he replied promptly, so many thanks to him for that. He says that SSR does try to load status icons from the current theme but that Ubuntu uses its own implementation of status icons called application indicators. He wonders if Ubuntu is doing something 'wierd' in this regard. he suggests I might want to update some icon caches and see if that works. Can anybody help me out with icon caches and how to update them ? Also, does anybody know how Ubuntu might be messing up the conversion between status icons and application indicators ? Thanks.

Comment: Your replies are certainly helpful, but alas your answer is not correct for me. My application icons are working perfectly, it is my status icons I am having problems with.